# Error in Angular console, but logic is working perfectly

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to fetch and populate the details of logged in user after logging in. The logic is working and I could see all the details from database in my application, but in vscode console am getting a console error that "id" property doesn't exist:

```
 "Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Object'." 

 this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  id: [''], 
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', Validators.required],
  });

 this.mainService.getUserData()
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(item => {
        this.myForm.patchValue(item);
        console.log(item.id); // am getting all values in browser console
        this.myForm.patchValue({
          id: item.id,
        })
      });
console.log(this.myForm); //all values i could see in browser console
```

Comment: for quick fix you can add  type `any` to `.subscribe((item:any) => {`

Comment: please post the type of item and myForm variables

Comment: You should add the return type of the methode "this.mainService.getUserData()" if it's done yet.

Comment: @Edison this solution worked for me! may I know the permanent solution, Thanks! I think we need to create specific types with interfaces for that method?

Comment: @Lautre I have  tried adding return type for getUserData method but haven't helped! But I wonder most of the other methods without return types are working fine!

Comment: @AmDGrtst you are correct, you need to create Models